# Why outer class can not be declared static?

Tags: java

I am trying to declare outer class as static.But when i do that it is throwing compile time error.Could you guys tell me why we can not declare outer class as static.

Comment: What would `static` even mean for a `class` that is not a member of another `class`?

Comment: What would it mean to declare an outer class as static?